# algebraic intersection number between two homology classes of simple closed curves on a surface

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

The Algebraic intersection number between two simple closed curves $a$ and $b$ intersect at some transverse points on a surface is defined by the sum of indices assigned to the points of intersection between $a$ and $b$ where the index is +1 if the orientation of $a$ and $b$ at $p$  matches with the orientation of the surface and -1 otherwise. The algebraic intersection number is well defined on homology classes. I'm asking where can I find this definition. When I googled about the algebraic intersection number I found that it is introduced by A. Scott and P. Swarup but I could not follow their definition. Is their definition equivalent to the one above.

Comment: What is their (Scott, Swarup) definition?

Comment: I really don't understand their original definition.

Comment: See Guillemin and Pollack, "Differential Topology" for the general definition and discussion of algebraic intersection numbers between submanifolds in a smooth manifold.

Comment: Scott and Swarup did not define algebraic intersection number for curves on surfaces. They defined the algebraic intersection number in a group theoretic context. Their definition recapitulated the classical definition.

Comment: Fine, thank you I got the definition from Guillemin and Pollack, "Differential Topology" book.